Is there a name for this matrix operation on binary matrices?
Let $M$ be a $m_1 \times m_2$ binary matrix and let $N$ be a $n_1 \times n_2$ binary matrix. Performing the operation between $M$ and $N$ is a binary $(m_1 + n_1 - 1) \times (m_2 + n_2 - 1)$ matrix, call it matrix $P$. Entry $(a,b)$ in matrix $P$ is $1$ if there exists a nonzero entry $(i,j)$ in $M$ and there exists a nonzero entry $(k,\ell)$ in $N$ such that $i+k-1=a$ and $j+\ell-1=b$.
Performing the operation between $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ results in the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.
From what I can tell, the operation forms a monoid with the binary matrices.
Does this operation have a name that anyone is familiar with?

This seems to basically be the Minkowski sum in matrix form.  I think you are doing $1$-based indexing (so top left entry is (1,1)) - if you do $0$-based indexing it's a bit simpler. If you consider the sets $S_M = {(i,j): M_{ij} = 1}$ then you are basically doing a sum of sets of vectors: $S_{M \star N} = S_M + S_N$, where $\star$ is your operation and $A+B = {a+b | a \in A, b \in B}$. But I don't know if there's a specific name for $\star$.

@JairTaylor, you are absolutely right, this is just Minkowski Sum on the nonzero entries of the matrices. In fact, when I formulated this operation for my project, I did 0-index my rows and columns to get exactly what you have here. Thank you so much!

NP! I added this as an answer.

This is the Minkowski sum of the nonzero entries, if you change your definition slightly by $0$-indexing, so that the $(a,b)-$entry has a $1$ in the resulting matrix whenever $(i,j)$ and $(k,\ell)$ have ones in their respective matrices and $i+k=a$ and $j+\ell=b$. If you consider the sets of nonzero entries $S_M = \{(i,j): M_{ij} = 1\}$ then you are basically doing a sum of them, considered as vectors: $$S_{M \star N} = S_M + S_N,$$ where $\star$ is your operation and $A+B = \{a+b | a \in A, b \in B\}$. Of course the $\star$ operation requires a little more information, since we also keep track of the dimensions of the matrix, so $S_M = S_N$ does not imply $M=N$. I don't know if there's a specific name for $\star$.
